# Spinnaker: Deciding which stage to go next

Tags: spinnaker

I'm creating this scenario where:
Stage A which is a Jenkins,
Stage B which will run if Stage A is successful,
Stage C which will run if Stage A fail.

Answer (score 0):

In the desired pipeline select Stage A > Execution Options > If stage fails > ignore the failure

Stage B > Execution Options > Conditional on Expression > Add your expression when succesful

Stage C > Execution Options > Conditional on Expression > Add your expression when Stage A fails...

i made a short [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/d3b5UELSKE4) feel free to watch it.

Comment: The video is no longer available?

Comment: @RyanClemente someone took down the vid. :-(